# Tridion Outbound email unsubscribe link (OutboundEmail_UnsubscribeURL) is always generating invalid url

Tags: outbound-email

I am using the outbound email, the subscription confirmation link is working fine. But the uncubscribe link is always showing the link invalid. I check the query parameter it is different in confirmation and unsubscribe links. When I replace the confirmation link value of p parameter in the unsubscribe link. It works fine. Please help me how can i correct this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you please clarify where the problem is? How do you know the link is invalid? Does it not go to the correct tracking page? Is there an error in the logs?

Comment: Do you have an update? Did the problem go away or did you solve it? If it's the latter, it's okay to post your own answer :) It could help something else in the future.

Comment: Sorry peter for delaying response, I was on leave. The problem is that I have used the  <a href="@@OutboundEmail_UnsubscribeURL@@" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:underline;">@@footerunsubscribetext@@</a>  for generating the unscription links.

Comment: But whenever I click the above link in emails. The link is always throwing unsubscription failed. Basically It is not able to match the value of p parameter in querystring. One more thing It was working fine earlier, recently before couple of days I have changes the Idenfication source value. I guess it is breaking due to that. But i am not able to find any configuration related to that. Also the confirmation link is working fine, only unsubscribe link is having issue. Please help

Comment: In that case, I would first check if the Contact actually exists in the subscription management database.

Comment: I checked,, it is existing. Also when I try to create a new contact with same email it shows me the error that contact is already existing as well. This started happening after I changed the identification source value. Thanks

Comment: Hi Peter, I have got the issue, actually the email address which I was trying to unsubscribe was having two records in the audience manager with different identification values, so the tridion was trying to generate the invalid unsubscription link,. Just now I tried with a email email get it registered and tried unsubscribing it just worked fine.. Anyways thanks a lot for your support, probably you can answer this question with your last comment. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the Contact exists in the subscription management database and has the data you expect. If it does not, check what is going wrong with your Contact synchronization (services running, correct Synchronization Target, Address Book synchronized to the relevant Publications, etc.)